# count of unique data in one column of list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have got  list of lists, have to count number of unique values in one of the columns from that list.
I have got only to the point to extract that one column from the list by using the following

```
j = 1
    for i in range(len(table)):
    row = table[i]
    print(row[j])
```

how can I now count unique data in that column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `set` to find unique elements

```
column_index = 1  # Set which column you need
len(set(row[column_index] for row in table))
```

OR

```
columns = list(zip(*table))
len(set(columns[column_index])) # Number of unique items
sum(columns[column_index]) # Sum of column
```

Comment: and now if I would like to do mathematical operation on that column, return sum, mean and std dev?

Comment: You might wanna consider `numpy` for faster execution if you have multiple operations and/or a large data.

Comment: @SylwiaKmiec Without `numpy` you'd need to program mean and std. dev. yourself. It's not that hard.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa thanks,  ah, alright I will sneak in numpy there :-)

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa - I have double checked and in my assignment the teacher requires from us to not use numpy or pandas libraries.... :-(

Comment: is there a way to def function to this?

Comment: @SylwiaKmiec This is getting offtopic. Read a basic tutorial on Python to learn how to define functions. `sum` is already available, and can be helpful for the other two.

Answer (score 0):

First off, there is an awesome package called [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for these kind of operations, have a look!

But for your actual question, you could do something like this:

```
import numpy as np 

only_column_j = []
j = 1
for i in range(len(table)):
    row = table[i]
    only_column_j.append(row[j])

values, counts = np.unique(only_column_j, return_counts=True)
```

Comment: Using numpy just for getting unique is an overkill for such trivial problems. @Florian

Comment: thanks! the challenge here is that I should not use Pandas.... :-(

Comment: If pandas and numpy are not allowed, you can still make use of collections.Counter